# Setting property values not sticking / viewDidLoad being called multiple times in Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, properties, xcode4.3

So this is weird.

I have a property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) Something *something; // .h
@synthesize something=_something                  // .m
```

For some reason, setting that property isn't keeping `_something` set.

I even wrote a setter:

```
- (void)setSomething:(Something *)something {
    _something = something;
}
```

The passed `something` is a valid instance of the object. However, after stepping through the line `_something = something`, `_something` is nil and `something` is still a valid object.

This is making me crazy, because everything looks right to me. I've written this same kind of thing a thousand times. The only thing that's new is that this is in Xcode 4.3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

ETA: So, perhaps this is a hint? viewDidLoad is being called a whole whackload of times, in batches of 4. I'm using storyboards, so the view is automatically set properly. Maybe the view controller isn't properly getting loaded or initialized or something? I've got the class set and everything looks like it should be working, but it isn't.

Comment: You don't need to define _something in the interface as of Xcode 4.2. It's done automagically.

Comment: Did you try sendign `_something` to `NSLog` right after checking it in the assignment? This would help decide between a real issue and a debugger issue.

Comment: I did. It's nil. This is what's driving me nutso.

Comment: I know this may not fix the problem, but try renaming the parameter that you pass to your setter to, say, `somethingVal`, like this: `- (void)setSomething:(Something *)somethingVal {_something=somethingVal;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I'm not sure where this method came from, but this was in the SomethingViewControler code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

Because I'm using storyboards, the very presence of this method caused all manner of problems. I'm pretty embarrassed, because I probably copied it and pasted it from somewhere without thinking about it.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone. It only killed most of my day.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer so future visitors can spot the solution quickly. After all, something like this might happen to other people as well.

Comment: Oh yes. It was an extremely annoying idea to uncomment (aka override) `-(void)loadView` by default. The method came from the Xcode4.3 UIViewController class template. I wasted 30 minutes to figure out why ^&*#@!% viewDidLoad was called 5 #@^!& times and the view was still empty after this. %^&*$! APPLE.

Comment: btw, I filed a bug. The decision to uncomment -(void)loadView when we don't use "Create XIB for User Interface" does not make sense at all. They introduced storyboards as the new way to do things, hence "no xib". So they should not force me to remove `loadView` each time I create a viewController. It was totally unexpected that this method is actually active. I wasted almost an hour.

Comment: DarkDust: I'll mark it as an answer as soon as SO allows me to. There is a two-day lock before I'm able to do so. I guess replacing people from answering their own questions too soon with comments that people should mark the answer when they can't is the price being paid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the thing you're assigning to that property is't pointed to from anywhere else. So after the assignment the only pointer to that object is your property and it's **week** so the object is thrown out of heap

Comment: I've tried making it strong, but that didn't fix the problem either. :-( Thanks though.